# Australian Immigration Visa 190 ABN work experience evidence

Tags: australia

I have applied for a 190 visa with work experience. I have been working on ABN for 2 years and then my employer offered me a full time role. Thus, I started working on TFN. But I am claiming points for experience for those 2 years I have been working as a sole trader. I have provided 3 payslips/invoices and my Tax Notice of assessment. My CO contacted me with the following query.:

> Provide evidence of your claimed period of employment prior to the
> date of invitation. Full Stack Software Developer, from 09/2017
>
> - bank statement showing salary credit for at least one year
> - group certificates/payment summaries
> - detailed superannuation contributions for at least one year

I do have bank statements that I can provide.
I do not have group certificates or payment summaries as I was working on ABN.
I never paid my self super because it was not mandatory.

What should I reply with?

Comment: Why can’t you reply with the explanation you’ve provided in your question and ask them what other evidence would be acceptable?

Comment: I will shortly. But I want to know if there is anything I have missed so I can provide them with the documents too.

Comment: Bro..may i know what happened to your file.what have you submitted and what is the outcome.

Comment: sorry for the late response . I provided them with an explanation of my ABN gave them invoices and my PR was granted